# Wordpress - wp_handle_upload - how to get the file name/directory of the uploaded file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website which allows users to upload files upon registration. I got the upload and registration portion working. Below is the code that handles the upload once the user clicks the register button:

```
function text_domain_woo_save_reg_form_fields($customer_id) {
    //First name field
    if (isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']));
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']));
    }
    //Last name field
    if (isset($_POST['billing_last_name'])) {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']));
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']));
    }
            // $target_path = "c:/"; 
        // $target_path = $target_path.basename( $_FILES['image_verification']['name']); 
        // echo " <script>console.log('it hit!!'); </script>";
        // echo " <script>console.log('image upload - success! " . $target_path . "' ); </script>";
        // if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_verification']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
            // echo "File uploaded successfully!";
            // echo " <script>console.log('image upload - success!'); </script>";
            // echo " <script>console.log('image upload - success! " . $target_path . "' ); </script>";
        // } else { 
            // echo "Sorry, file not uploaded, please try again!"; 
            // echo " <script>console.log('image upload - fail!'); </script>";
            // echo " <script>console.log('image upload - success! " . $target_path . "' ); </script>";
        // } 

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image_verification'];
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, array('test_form' => false));

    if ($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])) {
        var_dump($movefile);
    } else {
        echo $movefile['error'];
    }

}
```

The wp_handle_upload moves the file the user uploads into the C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2018\07\imgname.png directory.

now my concern here is:

if 2 users register and they both upload the file imgname.png, it will rename the second "imgname.png" to "imgname-1.png". This is perfectly fine but I am trying to also store a reference to these images in the database, how would I be able to know if the image got renamed or not?

Do you guys have any suggestions for this?

Example: UserA signing up uploads a file called "test.png", i want to create a record in the db like this:

```
|UserA|localhost\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2018\07\test.png.|
```

Now UserB signing up uploads a file called "test.png", his file will be renamed "test-1.png". Therefore I would need to create a record in the DB for him as the following:

```
|UserA|localhost\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2018\07\test-1.png.|
```

How would I get the directory/image name of the file if the change to "test 1.png" happened after it was uploaded?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you seeing the new filename when you call `var_dump($movefile);`? Do you see the original filename if you call `var_dump( $_FILES['image_verification'] );`?

Comment: @JasonB Var_Dump kept redirecting me to a blank page with a random array print out so i commented that line out. This is actually a good idea though, I will give that a try and see what I get as an output. If it gives me the new file name it should be exactly when I need. I appreciate your response, I'm still new to development so I have a ton of dumb questions haha

Comment: @JasonB this is the output i get from 
    var_dump($_FILES['image_verification']); array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "testimg.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpzkiiSZ" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(1511) } It does not show the name of the new file (test-1.png)

Comment: When you said that `var_dump( $movefile )` redirected you to a random array, I assume that it is actually dumping out the results of the `wp_handle_upload` function which is an associative array which should include the new file name. Can you post the results of that call as well? I'm hoping you'll be able to just do a comparison of that original file name in `$_FILES` with the file name in `$movefile` to see if the filename was changed during the execution of `wp_handle_upload`

Comment: @JasonB yep, you are correct! var_dump($movefile) did end up printing the new file name. This is the output array(3) { ["file"]=> string(76) "/home/localhost/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/testimg-2.png" ["url"]=> string(69) "http://localhost.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/testimg-2.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" } "testimg-2" is the name of the new file. How could I retrieve this file name from the output?

Answer (score 0):

To access the new file name, you can use the php function basename() and give it the path returned from the wp_handle_upload() function and compare it to the file name that was uploaded.

```
$movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, array('test_form' => false));
$new_filename = basename( $movefile['file'] );
$filename_was_changed = new_filename !== $_FILES['image_verification']['name'];
```